# Unable to pass subprocess.PIPE to Process on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I have a script that works on linux but is not compatible with Python 3 on windows (Python 3.5.2 is the version tested). The goal of the script is to capture stdout/stderr of a subprocess in realtime. Here is a script that reproduces the error:

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys

from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
try:
    from Queue import Empty
except ImportError:
    from queue import Empty  # python 3.x

ON_POSIX = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names


def enqueue_output(out, q):
    for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
        q.put(line)
    out.close()


def output_monitor_queue(out):
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=enqueue_output, args=(out, q))
    p.start()
    return q, p


def update_from_output_queue(q, out):
    try:
        line = q.get_nowait()
    except Empty:
        return out

    out += str(line)
    return out


def runit():
    stdout, stderr = '', ''
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['ipconfig.exe'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    # We need to use subprocesses to capture the IO, otherwise they will block one another
    # i.e. a check against stderr will sit waiting on stderr before returning
    # we use Queues to communicate
    qout, pout = output_monitor_queue(proc.stdout)
    qerr, perr = output_monitor_queue(proc.stderr)

    prev_std = None

    # Loop until the process is complete + both stdout/stderr have EOFd
    while proc.poll() is None or pout.is_alive() or perr.is_alive():

        # Check for updates from either (non-blocking)
        stdout = update_from_output_queue(qout, stdout)
        stderr = update_from_output_queue(qerr, stderr)

        # If there are changes, update the db
        if (stdout, stderr) != prev_std:
            print(stdout, stderr)
            prev_std = (stdout, stderr)


runit()
```

On running it, the following error is thrown:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\failed.py", line 62, in 
>       runit()   File "C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\failed.py", line 44, in runit
>       qout, pout = output_monitor_queue(proc.stdout)   File "C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\failed.py", line 23, in output_monitor_queue
>       p.start()   File "C:\Users\IEUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py",
>   line 105, in start
>       self._popen = self._Popen(self)   File "C:\Users\IEUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py",
>   line 212, in _Popen
>       return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)   File
>   "C:\Users\IEUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py",
>   line 313, in _Popen
>       return Popen(process_obj)   File "C:\Users\IEUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py",
>   line 66, in **init**
>       reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)   File "C:\Users\IEUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py",
>   line 59, in dump
>       ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj) TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object

Has anyone encountered this problem and knows a working cross-platform solution?

Comment: On Linux, `proc.stdout` is presumably a OS fileno, which can be inherited by the subprocess.  On Windows it is probably a C runtime library fileno, which can't be inherited.  (The underlying handle can be inherited, but it won't be mapped to a fileno in the C runtime library in the child.)  Doesn't Python have any sort of support for threading, or non-blocking IO?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, `proc.stdout` is a `BufferedReader` object, which can't be serialized over the pipe that's used to send arguments to the child process. multiprocessing doesn't inherit handles in the child process, plus Python 3.4+ defaults to creating non-inheritable files anyway. And yes, Chrismit should be using `threading` instead of `multiprocessing` to avoid a deadlock here, just like the existing `Popen.communicate` method does.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, if you wanted to do this with `multiprocessing`, you'd need to pass the parent's handle value from `msvcrt.get_osfhandle(out.fileno())`. Then in the child call `new_handle = multiprocessing.reduction.steal_handle(os.getppid(), handle)`. Then get a file descriptor via `fd = msvcrt.open_osfhandle(new_handle, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_BINARY)` and open it as a `BufferedReader` via `out = open(fd, 'rb')`.

Comment: @eryksun Threading does not work actually. I can replace Process with Thread, but it fails to update in real time. I'll check the MS specific solution.

Comment: Threads should work. Create a thread to read from each file and poll the queue in the main thread. You only need one queue. In the worker threads I'd `put` a tuple of the decoded line (`str` doesn't work for that; use the `decode` method) and the name of the source stream (e.g. `'stdout'` or `'stderr'`) into the queue, which ensures that output from the two streams is identifiable but properly sequenced.

Comment: If you do use multiprocessing you'll also have to use a `multiprocessing.Queue` instead of a `queue.Queue`.

Comment: There's no way to make it update in real time.  That's a very common, well-understood problem, and it has to do with how the child process ("ipconfig" in the example code) behaves when standard output is a pipe.  Nothing *your* code does can fix it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston ipconfig is just a test program on windows (since the # of cli I know on windows is quite low). It's actually meant for running any scripts. It does work in realtime for other applications that stream their progress to stdout/stderr -- but not on windows

Comment: @eryksun running two threads appears to work just as well w/o the need for pickling for multiprocessing. Thanks! Write it up for an answer and I can mark it

Comment: @HarryJohnston, I'm sure something *could* be done about standard I/O buffering by debugging the process (`DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS`) and injecting a DLL at the right time to call the C runtime's `setvbuf`. This would be the equivalent of the Linux loader's `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable, which the `stdbuf` command uses to modify buffering. I've never seen it done on Windows -- probably because there are so many versions of the CRT that you'd have to account for, and even multiple CRT's each with its own standard I/O `FILE` streams.

Comment: @eryksun: plus, there's no actual requirement that an executable use a Microsoft CRT, or indeed any CRT at all. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston, well, I was talking about a `stdbuf` implementation on Windows. Obviously it doesn't apply -- on any platform -- if the program doesn't use C standard `FILE` streams. For example, unlike Python 2, Python 3 has its own I/O implementation that doesn't use `FILE` streams, so `stdbuf` can't control Python 3 buffering on Linux.