# multiprocessing.Queue fails to queue subprocess.Popen object in python3

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.5, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to port some python 2 code to python 3. I am now faced with some difficulties with the multiprocess module. More precisely, the following piece of code works as expected in Python 2.7.11 (it spawns a new process using subprocess.Popen and redirects stdout).

```
import time
import pickle
import subprocess
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Manager

manager = Manager()

def execute(popen):
    stdout_lines = iter(popen.stdout.readline, "")
    for stdout_line in stdout_lines:
        yield stdout_line
    popen.stdout.close()
    return_code = popen.wait()

q = manager.Queue()
popen = subprocess.Popen(["python", "-u", "helloworld.py"],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        universal_newlines=True,
        bufsize=1)

q.put(popen)

try:
    for l in execute(popen):
        try:
            print(l)
        except socket.error as e:
            break
        except AttributeError as e:
            break
        except IOError as e:
            break
except:
    print("Finished.")

q.get().kill()
```

where the file `helloworld.py` contains a script printing helloworld every 2 seconds.

```
import time

while True:
    print("helloworld")
    time.sleep(2)
```

However, when run with python 3.5.3, it fails because it cannot serialize

```
`TextIOWrapper` object, which seems to be related to the redirected stream.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_subprocess.py", line 22, in <module>
    q.put(popen)
  File "<string>", line 2, in put
  File "/Users/scheibler/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 716, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
  File "/Users/scheibler/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/Users/scheibler/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

A little bit of research yielded this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664565/unable-to-pass-subprocess-pipe-to-process-on-windows). However it seems to be windows specific and the author mentions his code works under linux. I should also specify that I am running the code with Anaconda python under OS X.

Comment: It's not supposed to. Because it starts completely separate python interpreter. In this case you should use `multiprocessing.Process(target=FUNCTION_TO_RUN).start()`

Comment: Do you mean python 3 is not supposed to work this way ? I could try the way you suggest. It seems communication through pipes is possible too.

Comment: As far as I understand when you do `Popen` you start new instance of interpreter which is not connected to current one in any way. So you can't share any objects. In Any python doesn't mater 2 or 3.

Comment: The code above does work in python 2. A new interpreter is indeed started, but its standard input and output are redirected through pipes into the original process. The problem seems to be either with the implementation of pipes or queue in python 3.